# Register Account Firebase Through Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Context:** User opens app -> Clicks on Register -> Fills e-mail & Password -> Account created and returns to main screen.

User can login successful but I have to manually create an account on Firebase Browser in order to do this. I want to do this through the app instead.

Note: I am an amateur in Android-programming.

**Activity main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/snetech"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity** (Main Screen)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;

private Button mLoginBtn;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

    mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class));

            }
        }
    };

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startSignIn();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

private void startSignIn() {

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(!task.isSuccessful()){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign In Problem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

}

**FireApp**

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

/**
 * Created by Mertino11 on 10-Dec-16.
 */

public class FireApp extends Application {

@Override
public void  onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

**Register XML** (Page where user creates account)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="163dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/snetech"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textRegister"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.08" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailAccount"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/passwordAccount"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Create Account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/registerAccount" />
```

How it looks now:

[image: Main Screen]

[image: Registration Page]

I know I have to use onClicklistener en some tools of Firebase, but I do not know to code them in a logical way.

Comment: have you read over the Firebase authentication documentation?

Comment: I am trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
```

In case you are wondering even after confirming the email, the `isEmailVerified()` returns false, it is because of a bug. You have to either reauthenticate the user, or downgrade your Firebase SDK.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to register a user

Comment: @cricket_007 I referred to the official documentation, which does.

Comment: Links to documentation are not answers. please provide relevant code for the question